# In R, How can I save the result of each iteration in a loop into a separate file?

Tags: r

The same question has been answered in [CRAN FAQ 7.34](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-save-the-result-of-each-iteration-in-a-loop-into-a-separate-file_003f), however, weird enough, while I tried this solution on my own PC for a toy example as follows

```
for (i in 1:100) {
     x <- 1
     fp <- file.path("Results", paste("result", i, ".rda", sep = ""))
     save(list = x, file = fp)
}
```

it doesn't work. The error message is:

```
Error in save(list = x, file = fp) : object ‘1’ not found
```

If I use

```
 for (i in 1:100) {
     x <- 1
     fp <- file.path("Results", paste("result", i, ".rda", sep = ""))
     save(x, file = fp)
}
```

It is still wrong, and the error message becomes

```
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
cannot open compressed file 'Results/result1.rda', probable reason 'No such
file or directory'
```

Can anyone please explain why it happened? And any way to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `save(x, file = fp)`.  The help file will tell you why this happened.

Comment: I tried, please see my edited question.

Comment: Is there a directory called "Results"?  you might need to create it with `dir.create()`

Comment: Do you mean I need to create `Results` before this piece of code?

Comment: OK, after I created `Results`, problem solved. Thank you very much.